# How do I create an immutable value in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a random value from a function like this:

```
var randomString = function(length) {
        var chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');

        if (! length) {
            length = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        }

        var str = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            str += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
        }
        return str;
    }
```

And then:

```
var id = randomString(10);
```

But when I try to use the "id" variable it's a different value each time, because it's calling the function each time.

I've tried putting it in an object and freezing it like this:

```
var id = {};
Object.defineProperty( id, "id", {
  value: randomString(10),
  writable: false,
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false
});
         var newid = Object.freeze(id);
```

but it's still getting a new random string each time I try to use the "newid.id" variable.

How do I use the same random string twice?  Is there a way to freeze it or make it constant?

Comment: That is not true.  Your function will only run once.

Comment: Your `id` variable should be constant when running the above code. I've just tested and verified that logging `id` multiple times logs the same output each time: https://jsfiddle.net/3cs76r5b/. How are you using the `id` variable?

Comment: Show us the complete code. Most likely you have multiple `id` variables in there without noticing it (e.g. executing the function that contains it multiple times). If you worry about `id` being reassigned, make it a `const` instead of a `var`; and don't worry about string values, they cannot be mutated.

Comment: @ObsidianAge  It's in an angular.forEach loop inside of an async.eachOfSeries loop - maybe that's why?  I don't know, thanks for trying though.

Comment: @jthomasbailey Well yes, put it outside of the loop if you don't want to get a new random value on every iteration.

Comment: @Bergi here's a stripped down version https://pastebin.com/rrzdYygD I think it has to have something to do with the async

Comment: No. It has to do with the loops!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I'm an idiot.  Value was being changed somewhere else.

Comment: You might just want to delete your question then.

Answer (score -2):

That will be very easy to use php session. But, how about using javascript cookie? check it out: **JS Cookie** at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: No, I think I have a fair idea what he wants to do. To be able to use a random string twice, he could have used the local storage to store the first generated id in either a session or cookie. Was I wrong?

Comment: That's not directly addressing the problem, which is more simple than using cookies or PHP.

Comment: PHP? The OP didn't say anything about which server-side tech he is using. (The code shown in the question could even run server-side itself in Node.js.)